# Download and Parse Json File Server Side

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I am learning for the first time how to get a json file from a third party vendor and I am trying to do such with steam.  I am trying to retrieve game name and play time of a specific game for a specific user.  Based on the online documentation I have read the following code should be working, but the problem is that I am getting back a null.  If I take the generated URL and put it in the browser I get back results which means my URL is good, but the way I am parsing it is wrong.

```
public class SteamMemberViewModel
{
    public List<SteamGameViewModel> games { get; set; }
}

public class SteamGameViewModel
{
    public int appid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int playtime_forever { get; set; }
}

private string GetSteamGame()
{
    const int rocketLeagueId = 252950;

    var format = string.Format("http://api.steampowered.com/{0}/{1}/v{2}/?key={3}&steamid={4}&include_appinfo=1&format=json", "IPlayerService", "GetOwnedGames", "0001", "ABC", "123");

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SteamMemberViewModel>(wc.DownloadString(format));

        var rocketLeage = json.games.Where(g => g.appid == rocketLeagueId);
            var steamGameViewModels = rocketLeage as SteamGameViewModel[] ?? rocketLeage.ToArray();
        if (steamGameViewModels.Count() == 1)
        {
            var playtime = steamGameViewModels.First().playtime_forever;
            return steamGameViewModels.First().name + " - " + playtime;
        }
    }
    return "Steam Game Not Found";
}
```

The error that I Get is

> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: source
>
> Line 26:                 var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(wc.DownloadString(format));
> Line 27:
> Line 28:                 var rocketLeage = json.games.Where(g => g.appid == rocketLeagueId);
> Line 29:                 var steamGameViewModels = rocketLeage as SteamGameViewModel[] ?? rocketLeage.ToArray();
> Line 30:                 if (steamGameViewModels.Count() == 1)
>
> Source File: e:_websites\Local\Projects\Azularis\Azularis.System.Events\Azularis.System.Events\Controllers\HomeController.cs    Line: 28

EDIT:

I have also tried running the code as follows:

```
var result = wc.DownloadString(format);

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SteamMemberViewModel>(result);
var count = data.games.Count();
return count.ToString();
```

And I still got the same error.  result comes back with values though.

JSON FILE EXAMPLE:

```
{
    "response": {
        "game_count": 16,
        "games": [
            {
                "appid": 10,
                "name": "Counter-Strike",
                "playtime_forever": 5019,
                "img_icon_url": "6b0312cda02f5f777efa2f3318c307ff9acafbb5",
                "img_logo_url": "af890f848dd606ac2fd4415de3c3f5e7a66fcb9f",
                "has_community_visible_stats": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Value games inside SteamMemberViewModel is always null.

Comment: Have you tried breaking your statement down into more digestible parts? Maybe download the json string and store it in a string variable. Then pass the string variable to DeserializeObject. That way you can add a breakpoint and see what the json object you're receiving looks like.

Comment: @itsme86 yes I have, I updated my answer.  I still get the same error.  The result is downloaded and the value is retrieved from steam, however it fails to convert it to an object.

Comment: What does the json string look like? It just has those 3 values?

Comment: @itsme86 I updated the question with the json file example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think your issue is that your top object in the JSON is response but you are trying to parse that into the equivalent of the games array. I would think you need to get the array object and then parse so you need to go down a level into the JSON object.

I can't be sure as you do not know if that serializer is performing some recursive work until it finds the object (I doubt it though) but the docs does not seem to do so:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

in the example, it clearly states you need to get down to the object you mean to be your top level. And it is not response in your example.

So you'd have to do something like (pseudo-code):

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonString); 
IList<JToken> array = json["response"]["games"].Children().ToList();
if(array != null)
{
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SteamMemberViewModel>(array.ToString());
}
```

Comment: what is result in your example?

Comment: I don't use that json parser so I just assume the problem as it would be the case with what I use. I have not tried your example. Is this above still not working for you?

Comment: you are correct as to that being the problem, I am now trying to figure out how to properly parse this.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already have an accepted answer. Your issue is easily fixable. Replace `SteamMemberViewModel` code with below code.

```
public class SteamMemberViewModel
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int game_count { get; set; }
    public Game[] games { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public int appid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int playtime_forever { get; set; }
    public string img_icon_url { get; set; }
    public string img_logo_url { get; set; }
    public bool has_community_visible_stats { get; set; }
}
```